# Optional field inside Options React Select

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

Hey guys im trying to create a autosuggestion in cooperation with redux-form. Im using the Creatable approach. I loading my options via an external API. The problem is, i need a extra field in every Option Object. `{value: "test@gmx.de", label: "test@gmx.de", dn:"CN...." }`. Is there a possibility to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically add my own properties inside the callback for the API request, just before setting the options in the state. For example...

```
    axios.get('/some/api/request')
    .then(response => {

        const options = response.data.map(item => {
            // Add whatever custom properties you want here
            return ({value: "test@gmx.de", label: "test@gmx.de", dn:"CN...." })
    }) 

    // set your options in the state to the new options constant from above
    dispatch(change('formName', 'options', options))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was also my first thought. Unfortunately it looked like React-Select couldn't handle this kind of Option structure. I was getting a weird view. Maybe my whole logic has a issue. Like I said, I use React-Select Creatable. I load my options via the loadOption prop and the callback Function. I do not get my options via redux-form.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Handle change with either selectedOption
  handleChange(selectedOption){
    this.setState({ selectedOption })
    if(this.props.onOptionSelect){
      this.props.onOptionSelect(selectedOption.data)
    }
  }

  loadOptions(input, callback) {
    this.props.loadOptions(input).then(options => {
      callback(null, {options: options})
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {selectedOption} = this.state
    const selectClass = this.props.meta.touched && this.props.meta.error ? "has-error form-group" : "form-group"
    return (
      <div className={selectClass}>
        <AsyncCreatable
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
          isLoading={false}
          placeholder={this.props.label}
          promptTextCreator={(label) => this.props.promtLabel(label)}
          onBlur={() => this.props.input.onBlur(selectedOption.value || "")}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }


//Function to convert incomming users in usable options (React Select)
export const convertADUsersToOptions = users => {
  return users.map(user => {
    return {
      value: normalizeDN(user.dn),
      label: user.mail
    }
  })
}
```